# Disable Right Click On Webworks App

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Particular page of the application, I want to disable the back button and I want to use the blackberry menu.

How do I disable the back button on a blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to trap the Back key event, and then handle it accordingly, like this...

```
function trapForBackKey() {
   blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, handleBack);  
}  

function handleBack() {
   alert("handle back button");  
}
```

In your case, you may want to just simply "return false;" in the handleBack function.